# How to SUM two row with the same id

Tags: java, sqlite

I have the database below its table name is marked,

[image: img]

please help me a code to create another table below

[image: Img1]

```
SELECT [ID] , sum([physics])
FROM [mark]
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Add also `sum([math]), sum([sum])` in the select list.

Answer (score 0):

Just add two more fields:

```
SELECT [ID] , sum([physics]), sum([math]), sum([sum]) 
FROM [mark]
GROUP BY [ID]
```

If you want to create a table use following script:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT [ID] , sum([physics]), sum([math]), sum([sum]) 
FROM [mark]
GROUP BY [ID]
```